# difference between OSX and Linux ssh in travis-ci?

Tags: macos, ssh, travis-ci

I have a small shell script which I use on Linux and OS-X travis instances to scp the artifacts to a server (akamai) I don't have shell access on (can't see the logs) and then change the name (via `ssh` command).

However—it works great on Linux, and doesn't work on OSX. The akamai server is running SSH-1.99-Server-VIII-hpn14v2.

For example, even something as simple as:

```
ssh user@remote 'ls -l'
```

…has issues.

When things run on linux, it works fine (output from `ssh -vvv`) (there isn't any interesting debug3 message between the send command, and the response with these versions of ssh).

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.10, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
[snip]
debug1: Sending command: ls -l
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
drwxrwxr-x rgetz4trav  storage            0 Feb 05 16:44 336936
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
```

when things run from OS-X, it never sees a response.

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
[snip]
debug1: Sending command: ls -l
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 6 len 0
debug2: channel 0: read failed
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
```

I have looked around - and have not been able to figure out what is different.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `ssh -vv` does not enough verbose-enough output to be able to tell what’s going on. Please run it with an addition `v`—`ssh -vvv`—and then [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42048955/edit) to add that `ssh -vvv` to it as an update.

Comment: What are the OpenSSH versions of the servers? What errors you see in the server log? What is your default shell for both users you are connecting to?

Comment: OSX ssh is a reasonably current version of OpenSSH, the same thing you'll find on Linux. If you have a server that's treating OSX clients differently from Linux clients, you should be looking at the server configuration.

Comment: I added some info back into the question - as mentioned I don't have access to either logs - one is a travis-CI container, the other is a network storage.

Answer (score 0):

I think the final answer was ssh and scp compatibility on akamai has known issues, so I needed to abandon ssh/scp and switch to sftp (which works).

The docs state: "Various Protocol-specific Limitations May Exist".